# How to enable full-text searches within the Content Editor?

Tags: content-search

Our client would like to do full-text searches within all of their Content (e.g. the values of the Rich Text Fields). Is it possible to enable this within the standard Content Editor search function? If not, is it possible to extend the standard search somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behaviour. Sitecore will index all fields on Lucene, using the vanilla configuration setup.

From `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.Config`:

```
        <fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldTypeName">
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="attachment"                         storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="checkbox"                           storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="checklist"                          storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="custom"                             storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="datasource"                         storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="date"                               storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.DateTime" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="datetime"                           storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.DateTime" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="droplink"                           storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="droplist"                           storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="droptree"                           storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="file drop area"                     storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="file"                               storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="general link with search"           storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="general link"                       storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="grouped droplink"                   storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="grouped droplist"                   storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="icon"                               storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="iframe"                             storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="image"                              storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="integer"                            storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.Int32"    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="internal link"                      storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="layout"                             storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="link"                               storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="lookup"                             storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="memo"                               storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="multi-line text"                    storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="multilist with search"              storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="multilist"                          storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="name lookup value list"             storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="name value list"                    storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="number"                             storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.Double"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="page preview"                       storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="password"                           storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="profile card value"                 storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="profile cards"                      storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="query datasource"                   storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="reference"                          storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="rendering datasource"               storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="rich text"                          storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="rules"                              storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="security"                           storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="server file"                        storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="single-line text"                   storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="template field source"              storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="text"                               storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="thumbnail"                          storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="tracking"                           storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="tree list"                          storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="tree"                               storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="treelist with search"               storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="treelist"                           storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="treelistex"                         storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="tristate"                           storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="valuelookup"                        storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="word document"                      storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
        </fieldTypes>
      </fieldMap>
```

Rich Text fields are included, as you can see. Also (from same configuration):

```
        <!-- This flag will index all fields by default. This allows new fields in your templates to automatically be included into the index.
           You have two choices : 

           1) Set this to 'true' and place all the fields that you would like to remove in the 'ExcludeField' list.
           2) Set to false and place all fields you would like to be indexed in the 'IncludeField' list below.
        -->
        <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>
```

For more information, see: [Searching](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/searching/searching)

Comment: Thank you. I have the same config settings and rich text fields' values are not found, only their names within the Content Editor. Is there anything you need to add to enable full text searches?

Comment: So to be more precise, if I add an RTE and type '12345' into it, I should be able to find the RTE when searching for '12345' in the Content Editor.

Comment: No, not from a vanilla setup. You might want to go to Control Panel to rebuild all your indexes. Also check logs for any exceptions coming from the indexing processes.

Comment: Yes. Entering '12345' into a RTE field, saving the item in question - you can expect it to be found using search within a couple of minutes.

Comment: You were correct, it was sufficient to rebuild the indexes. Issue resolved.